# How to enable emoji in Rmarkdown to show up after publishing in Shiny-Server

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, emoji, shiny-server

I have the following Rmarkdown code, which uses Hadley's **[emo(ji)](https://github.com/hadley/emo)** package.

````
---
title: "My First Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
```


Rows {data-height=800}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Section1 `r strrep(emo::ji("heart_eyes_cat"), 5)`

Some text
````

In my Rstudio IDE it has no problem generating this:

[image]

As highligted in the image the emoji failed to show up in my **[local Shiny-server.](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)**

How can I enable it?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated HTML? What web browser are you using? Tried any others? Did it log any errors when rendering the page?

Comment: @Spacedman I tried on FF, Safari, Chrome. No error in `/var/log/shiny-server.log`. Page source has hidden a lot of detailed. I cannot see any clue on the source.

Comment: No, the error (if any) will be in the browser's log.

Comment: @Spacedman What's the path for Shiny browser log?

Comment: It doesn't have a "path", its something your web browser can show you, via a menu or a developer tool bar button.

Comment: Can you also give the code you run to create the shiny app? Or are you clicking buttons in RStudio?

Comment: @Spacedman the code is in my OP. And in RStudio I just click on "Run Document"

Comment: @Spacedman Tried FF's Browser Console. Can't see any related error.

Comment: How does this get onto your shiny server?

Comment: @Spacedman 1. Save the Rmd in the directory e.g. `myapp` and 2. link it to shiny server using this command `sudo ln -s /home/pdubois/myapp /srv/shiny-server/myapp`

Comment: @pdubois does this solve your issue - http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#host-rmd ?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [github documentation](https://github.com/hadley/emo/commit/4be1aa3542a09c77aa9220a6dda1342d3956f062), your files should read something like the following:

```
S3method(print,emoji)
export(ji)
export(ji_find)
export(ji_p)


ji_p <- function(x) {
   stopifnot(is.numeric(x))

   out <- stats::symnum(x,
     corr = FALSE,
     na = FALSE,
     cutpoints = c(0, 1e-5, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),
     symbols = c(ji("laughing"), ji("joy"), ji("grin"), ji("smile"), ji("thinking"), ji("poop"))
   )

   structure(out, class = c("emoji", class(out)))

 }
```

I didn't see any shorthand indicated as you seem to have used (using the `, 5`) in your code and the `r` prefix seems now to have been removed; when used inline it is used but there is a need to use extra 'ticks' before and after it like so:

```
 `` `r emo::ji("smile")` ``
```

Are you using an older version of the commit? The need for knitr has been removed and it now requires only tibble. Check [this latest commit doc out](https://github.com/hadley/emo/commit/97754fd7a8704aeb25bfb7e7882bba226b6c81b1)

I hope this is of assistance